# C# Mail with Office 365 And Graph Client

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with Office 365 for sending Mail.
So I wrote a little DLL which includes a form for testing the configuration.
And a simple class for Creating the graphmail and sending it.

This works.

But:
In one Exe that call this Dll, the test form and the mail works!  fine
The process that send mails also works.

In another C# program I wrote, the test form and test mail works (it works everything I use it, whatever program calls it)
But the The process for Send Mailing won't send mail, without any error.
The process is exactly the same as in the first program...

I don't understand.

Solution:
I found the the reason of the issue... But not the solution. the mail sending is launch at the end of a process, with was started from the Main in Program. I add a windows splash after it, and then mails are correctly sent.

It seems mail is not really sent after the return of the:

```
   await _Office365Client.Users[_Office365Configuration.ClientId]
                      .SendMail(message, true)
                      .Request()
                      .PostAsync();
```

I had a System.threading.sleep(5000);
Which let the mail to be properly sent.

Comment: you should add some code to your question. because now it's just guessing for us

Comment: In addition to @Delanovanlonden 's suggestion, did you try the Debugger to find out what's going wrong?

Comment: I found the the reason of the issue ... But not the solution. the mail sendind is launch a the end of a process, with was started from the Main in Program. I add a windows splash after it, and then mails are correctly sended. I have to find now of I make wake the program for the mail sending before stop and without adding a form, the app isnot interative with user.